# jQuery How to Identify Parent Class

Tags: jquery, class

I have a jQuery click function that is setup to work within `<div>`'s defined with class attributes. I need to control the click() behavior based on the parent class as follows:

Sample HTML

```
<div class="rightContentBlock test">
    <img src="../themes/simple/images/close.png" alt="close button" class="closeButton" />
    <h3>Column Header</h3>
    <p>Column Content A</p>
</div> <!-- end rightContentBlock1 -->

<div class="rightContentBlock">
    <h3>Column Header</h3>
    <p>Column Content B</p>
</div> <!-- end rightContentBlock2 -->

<div class="rightContentBlock">
    <h3>Column Header C</h3>
        <p>Column Content</p>
</div> <!-- end rightContentBlock3 -->
```

jQuery Code

```
// toggle hidden block in profileBlock on page header
$('img.closeButton').click(function(){
    $('div.test').hide();
});
// end toggle hidden block
```

I can get this to work by hard coding the `test` class. I want to use the close button occasionally through my page. Is there any way to identify the `<div class="rightContentBlock">` without hard coding each block separately?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.rightContentBlock')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for jQuery's [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$('img.closeButton').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.rightContentBlock').hide();
});
```

Comment: Sounds cool @JosephSilber. I'll give it a try and post back shortly.

Comment: Awesome. That worked perfectly @JosephSilber. I need to wait for 9 minutes to accept your answer (pet peeve I dislike about this website). I'll have to accept it next time I come back...